# What can be work instead of this code?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield, multiplication

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        int num1=Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText());
        int num2=Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());
        int result=num1*num2;
        jTextField6.setText(result);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

    }          
}
```

Here's the code. I'm getting error on "   jTextField6.setText(**result**);" . As you can see i gave some bolt effect for you can see normally. What should i use instead of this ? 
This error coming out

"method setText in class JTextComponent cannot be applied to given types;
  required: String
  found: int
  reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion"

I'm trying to do: Take text from jtextfield4, take from jtextfield5 too. And multpilicate them and show the result in the jtextfield6. This is not fully automatic. I'm writing this code for a button. I'm waiting your advices. If you want more codes, graphics etc. Just leave a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume setText need to have text set.  How about

```
jTextField6.setText(""+result);
```

Comment: omg man you're amazing. Thanks, thanks a lot i'll accept is answer but i need 10-odd min

Comment: @Peter: Why the expensive `String` addition instead of `Integer.toString`?

Comment: @chrylis Compared to displaying some text on the screen, it is trivial.  `""+` is easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 2):

That error is saying that the method needs a `String` but you gave it an `int`. Use `Integer.toString(result)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is, in fact, rather clear:

> method `setText` in class `JTextComponent` cannot be applied to given types; required: `String` found: `int` reason: actual argument `int` cannot be converted to `String` by method invocation conversion.

This is because the `setText()` method needs a `String` argument, but you gave it an `int`. So you need to cast the `int` variable, or force Java to convert it into a `String`:

1. `Integer.toString(result)`
2. `"" + result`

In both cases, the result will be the same.